# How to interpret weight distributions of neural net layers

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have designed a 3 layer neural network whose inputs are the concatenated features from a CNN and RNN. The weights learned by network take very small values. What is the reasonable explanation for this? and how to interpret the weight histograms and distributions in Tensorflow? Any good resource for it?

This is the weight distribution of the first hidden layer of a 3 layer neural network visualized using tensorboard. How to interpret this? all the weights are taking up zero value?

[image]

This is the weight distribution of the second hidden layer of a 3 layer neural:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> how to interpret the weight histograms and distributions in Tensorflow?

Well, you probably didn't realize it, but you have just asked the 1 million dollar question in ML & AI...

*Model interpretability* is a hyper-active and hyper-hot area of current research (think of holy grail, or something), which has been brought forward lately not least due to the (often tremendous) success of deep learning models in  various tasks; these models are currently only black boxes, and we naturally feel uncomfortable about it...

> Any good resource for it?

Probably not exactly the kind of resources you were thinking of, and we are well off a SO-appropriate topic here, but since you asked...:

- A recent (July 2017) article in Science provides a nice overview of the current status & research: [How AI detectives are cracking open the black box of deep learning](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/07/how-ai-detectives-are-cracking-open-black-box-deep-learning) (no in-text links, but googling names & terms will pay off)
- DARPA itself is currently running a program on [Explainable Artificial Intelligence (XAI)](https://www.darpa.mil/program/explainable-artificial-intelligence)
- There was a workshop in NIPS 2016 on [Interpretable Machine Learning for Complex Systems](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.gr/2016/12/nips2016-interpretable-machine-learning.html)

On a more practical level:

- The Layer-wise Relevance Propagation (LRP) toolbox for neural networks ([paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v17/15-618.html), [project page](http://www.explain-ai.org/), [code](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox), [TF Slim wrapper](https://github.com/VigneshSrinivasan10/interprettensor))
- FairML: Auditing Black-Box Predictive Models, by Fast Forward Labs ([blog post](http://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2017/03/09/fairml-auditing-black-box-predictive-models.html), [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04967), [code](https://github.com/adebayoj/fairml))
- A very recent (November 2017) paper by Geoff Hinton, [Distilling a Neural Network Into a Soft Decision Tree](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09784), with an independent [PyTorch implementation](https://github.com/kimhc6028/soft-decision-tree)
- SHAP: A Unified Approach to Interpreting Model Predictions ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07874), authors' [code](https://github.com/slundberg/shap))

These should be enough for starters, and to give you a general idea of the subject about which you asked...

**UPDATE** (Oct 2018): I have put up a much more detailed list of practical resources in my answer to the question [Predictive Analytics - “Why” factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391871/predictive-analytics-why-factor/52392344#52392344)

Answer (score 2):

> The weights learned by network take very small values. What is the reasonable explanation for this? How to interpret this? all the weights are taking up zero value?

Not all weights are zero, but many are. One reason is regularization (in combination with a large, i.e. wide layers, network) Regularization makes weights small (both L1 and L2). If your network is large, most weights are not needed, i.e., they can be set to zero and the model still performs well.

> How to interpret the weight histograms and distributions in Tensorflow? Any good resource for it?

I am not so sure about weight distributions. There is some work that analysis them, but I am not aware of a general interpretation, e.g., for CNNs it is known that center weights of a filter/feature usually have larger magnitude than those in corners, see [Locality-Promoting Representation Learning, 2021, ICPR, https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10661]
For CNNs you can also visualize weights directly, if you have large filters. For example, for (simpl)e networks you can see that weights first converge towards some kind of class average before overfitting starts. This is shown in Figure 2 of [The learning phases in NN: From Fitting the Majority to Fitting a Few, 2022, http://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08299]
Rather than going for weights, you can also look at what samples trigger the strongest activations for specific features. If you don't want to look at single features, there is also the possibility to visualize what the network actually remembers on the input, e.g., see [Explaining Neural Networks by Decoding Layer Activations, https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.13630].
These are just a few examples (Disclaimer I authored these works) - there is thousands of other works on explainability out there.