# Is it possible to overfit on 250,000 examples in a few epochs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Generally speaking, is it possible to tell if training a given neural network of depth X on Y training examples for Z epochs is likely to overfit? Or can overfitting only be detected for sure by looking at loss and accuracy graphs of training vs test set?

Concretely I have ~250,000 examples, each of which is a flat image 200x200px. The model is a CNN with about 5 convolution + pooling layers, followed by 2 dense layers with 1024 units each. The model classifies 12 different classes. I've been training it for about 35 hours with ~90% accuracy on training set and ~80% test set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Generally speaking, is it possible to tell if training a given neural network of depth X on Y training examples for Z epochs is likely to overfit?

Generally speaking, **no**. Fitting deep learning models is still an almost exclusively empirical art, and the theory behind it is still (very) poor. And although by gaining more and more experience one is more likely to tell beforehand if a model is prone to overfit, the confidence will generally be not high (extreme cases excluded), and the only reliable judge will be the experiment.

Elaborating a little further: if you take the Keras MNIST CNN [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) and remove the intermediate dense layer(s) (the previous version of the script used to include 2x200 dense layers instead of 1x128 now), thus keeping only conv/pooling layers and the final softmax one, you will end up with ~ 98.8% *test* accuracy after only 20 epochs, but I am unaware of anyone that could reliably predict this beforehand...

> Or can overfitting only be detected for sure by looking at loss and accuracy graphs of training vs test set?

Exactly, this is the only safe way. The telltale signature of overfitting is the *divergence* of the learning curves (training error still decreasing, while validation or test error heading up). But even if we have diagnosed overfitting, the *cause* might not be always clear-cut (see a relevant question and answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672700/validation-loss-decreases-quickly-then-steadily-increases/47701566#47701566)).

> ~90% accuracy on training set and ~80% test set

Again very generally speaking and only in principle, this does not sound bad for a problem with 12 classes. You already seem to know that, if you worry for possible overfitting, it is the curves rather than the values themselves (or the training time) that you have to monitor.

---

On the more general topic of the poor theory behind deep learning models as related to the subject of model intepretability, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745313/how-to-interpret-weight-distributions-of-neural-net-layers/47752092#47752092) of mine useful...