# How to identify most relevant filters for a particular class

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Let's say I have binary classification task and I'm using a CNN. Simply visualizing the CNN isn't very helpful as the input isn't images. However, I would like to know which particular filters contribute the most for an input sample to be considered a particular class. 
Given the following architecture (implemented using Keras), how do I achieve this?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(10, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (10, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I explored resources [A](https://ml4a.github.io/ml4a/looking_inside_neural_nets/) and [B](https://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/). But neither seem helpful for what I want to do. If there are other suggestions for understanding what a network learns for non-image datasets, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: You *may* find something suitable in the general list here (which I am trying to keep up to date): [Predictive Analytics - “why” factor & model interpretability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391871/predictive-analytics-why-factor-model-interpretability/52392344#52392344)

Comment: This is mostly based on instincts, but you can try the following. 1. Take a random sample of data for a given class. 2. Feed forward 3. Compute the average/maximum activation for each kernel 3. For each layer, get the n kernels that were maximally activated. But this is just for identifying the most-contributing kernels. Not really sure about visualizing what's learned.